# Vertical space in table (not arraystretch)

Tags: tables, rules, vertical-spacing

I want a vertical space in one row of a table without stretching out all rows of the table. The suggestions I see all involve `\arraystretch{}`, but I want the text-only row to still be small.

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Tally of pink beads     & Tally of blue beads \\ \hline
\vspace{.5in}     &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\vfill

\end{document}
```

[image: table with a vertical gap in the walls of the enlarged cell]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert a vertical strut (a zero-width `\rule`) of appropriate length (height):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
  \hline
  Tally of pink beads & Tally of blue beads \\
  \hline
  \vspace{.5in}       &                     \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ | c | c | }
  \hline
  Tally of pink beads & Tally of blue beads \\
  \hline
  \rule{0pt}{.5in}    &                     \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

In your setup (with `\vspace`) the vertical space is inserted *after* the line break `\\` when the vertical rules for that row has already been inserted. So, setting a zero-width `\rule` within the line keeps TeX in horizontal mode, allowing the vertical rules to stretch across the entire row's height.